# What does $\Bbb N \to \Bbb R^{\ge 0}$ mean?

Tags: functions

What is the interpretation of this:

Functions $$a,b,c\colon\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ^{\ge 0}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard notation for functions, a function $f$ has domain $X$ and range $Y$. We write $f:X \longrightarrow Y$. In this case we have functions from $\mathbf{N}$ to $\mathbf{R}^{\geq 0}$, the non-negative reals. Note, infinite sequences, such as $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbf{N}}$ are examples of such functions, so long as $x_n \geq 0$ for all $n\geq1$.

Comment: However, $\mathbf{R}^{\geq 0}$ is not standard.

Comment: What do you mean, I've seen this notation used many times before.

Comment: $\Bbb R_{\ge0}$ commonly means non-negative reals.

Comment: I have seen it many times myself, but it is far from standard. Yet another one: $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: I would never use $\Bbb R^{\ge0}$. Too easy to confuse with notation like $\Bbb R^{<\omega}$.